# Unix script with || not working

Tags: unix

I am writing a unix script which looks like

```
#!/bin/ksh

switch=$1
echo $switch
if [ $switch != "on" ] || [ $switch != "off" ]
then
     echo "Some message blah "
     exit 0
fi
```

I run the script as ksh test.ksh on and pass an argument at runtime But the code is not working. Regardless of me passing 'on' or 'off' on the console i get Some message blah. Please let me know how to rectify this.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition will always evaluate to true since `$switch` cannot be `on` and `off` at the same time. In natural language it could be worded as:

> if $switch is not "on" or $switch is not "off" then...

One of these two conditions will always be true. Perhaps you meant to use `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the update. I was so wrong logically. Thanks for this correction